# WebGL: Texture access in a vertex shader?

Tags: textures, webgl, vertex-shader

Is it possible to read from a texture in a **vertex** shader with WebGL?

I wrote a [WebGL page](http://steveharoz.com/test/webgl/) (just to try it out) and used Chrome 7 to test it. As soon as I upgraded to Chrome 8, it stopped working. I double checked that webgl is enabled. The error is:

> 'texture2D': no matching overloaded function found

When I replace the call to texture2D with a constant, it works.
Texture access in a fragment shader using the same texture also works.

Anyone have any ideas? I'm particularly thrown by the fact that upgrading Chrome caused it to break.

**Update:** It works in firefox 4 beta. I reported a bug with Chrome - issue 65340

**Update 2:** It now works in Firefox and Chrome

Comment: I think this could be a limitation of some implementations.

Comment: I doubt that it's intentional. That would limit a lot of techniques (e.g. displacement mapping).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its not really a 'bug' in Chrome.

Vertex texture access is not a required feature of Open GL ES 2, which is the basis of the WebGL specification. I suspect what might be happening is that although your underlying GL driver supports vertex texture access, now you've switched to Chrome its using Angle, and Angle doesn't report that vertex texture access as available.

You can compare your FF and Chrome versions by using Thatcher Ulrich's

http://webgl-bench.appspot.com/

This has the MAX_VERTEX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS parameter (near the end) Chrome/Angle always reports 0.t

Another thing to check is that you are using the correct texture2D syntax - the spec changed and it may be that FF is stil supporting the older syntax.

Comment: That site is great. Thanks.

It actually worked in Chrome 7 (I tried downgrading). Any idea why they would drop the feature? Is there any benefit to blocking the hardware's capability?

Comment: As einSelbst says below, its not a question of 'dropping' a feature. Angle uses DX9 to emulate Open GL ES 2.0, and the minimum vertex texture count for ES 2.0 is 0. If you select the non Angle renderer it will use the underlying graphics cards Open GL implementation, which may well support the feature. Please note that by default both FF and Chrome will use Angle. I suggest you look at the Angle project and maybe ask them if they'd like to implement vertex texture support. See http://code.google.com/p/angleproject/

Comment: Thanks. I replied to your and einSelbst's comments below.

Comment: Hi Sharoz I actually raised an issue myself on the Angle mailing list - I got answer from Daniel Koch saying that they've looked at VTUs but not so far implemented it. You are correct below that only D3D9 HSLS V 3+ supports vertex texture shaders. FF has only just switched to Angle by default. I've decided to see if I can find some time to look at the Angle implementation and maybe propose a patch, but there are some problems.

Comment: Oops, I just saw this comment. Thanks for looking into this! I'll check out the Angle mailing list.

Answer (score 2):

It would like to comment, but I don't have the reputation.

As alanatmech said, it might be related to Angle, which forwards all GL calls into DirectX.
So it is not a feature dropping and the benefit would be, to have WebGL support on Windows machines without OpenGL Drivers.

You can try to run Chrome with "--use-gl=desktop", so it will use the OpenGL rendering backend instead of Angle.
Your site is not working for me with Chrome 8.0.552.215 beta than either, but it doesn't give the error you mentioned, which I do get on Chrome 9.0.597.10 canary build without the flag AND on Minefield.

Comment: I didn't realize that it was using DX. Apparently, older (or more limited) variants of DX9 can't make vertex texture calls (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shader_Model_3#Vertex_shader_comparison). 

What's interesting is that it works in firefox 4. Perhaps they're using different versions of Angle? Or maybe firefox is routing it through opengl?

Comment: Only Chrome uses Angle (at the moment). Firefox 4 (Beta 7) is still using OpenGL. My guess is that it's just not implemented.

Comment: Since the 4th of December it (Angle/D3D) is enabled by default in the firefox nightlies for 32bit windows and I guess beta8pre too.